Can you stay in a hotel in Barcelona as an 18-year-old with a friend who's 17 and share a room together?
Can you stay in a hotel in Barcelona as an 18-year-old with a friend who's 17 and share a room together?

Are you asking for the legal position or for hotel policy (the two may or may not be the same). Any hotel in particular?

The 17-year old is a minor and I assume the 18-year old is not their legal guardian?
